# How to get the device orientation changed event under Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

With windows phone, is there an event I can register for when the device entered landscape mode?

The reason why I am asking this is because we have a view with an input box. And when in landscape mode, the `TextBox` is partially blocked by the keyboard. So I am thinking may have to hide some additional information on the page when it is in landscape mode (for example, hide the title of the page and etc.).

The following is a simple example. 
Left: Before keyboard is shown; Right: After keyboard is shown.

[image]
[image]

---

I posted another question related to this and has a better solution as far as I am concerned:

[Why isn't the TextBox inside ContentDialog automatically scroll above keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210044)

But no matter what, here is the complete code for orientation change event:

```
// Define this in the class 
private SimpleOrientationSensor _simpleorientation;

// Put hits in the Constructor
_simpleorientation = SimpleOrientationSensor.GetDefault();
if (_simpleorientation != null)
{
    _simpleorientation.OrientationChanged += new TypedEventHandler<SimpleOrientationSensor, SimpleOrientationSensorOrientationChangedEventArgs>(OrientationChanged);
}

// Event function
private void OrientationChanged(object sender, SimpleOrientationSensorOrientationChangedEventArgs e)
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
          // ...
    });
}
```

Comment: Silverlight or XAML?

Comment: @IgorKulman, it is for xaml. Just added a new tag.

Comment: [PhoneApplicationPage.OrientationChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.orientationchanged(v=vs.105).aspx) or just look at SizeChanged on the window, did ya even bother with a quick search for this? Oh, and PS, Silverlight uses xaml...

Comment: @ChrisW. Thanks for the comments. But still super newbie to this. Could you give me a bit more information about how or where to register this event? Can I do it within xaml? I tried things like **<Grid OrientationChanged="OrientationChangedEventHandler">** but it is throwing me error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet would be describing to `Windows.Current.SizeChanged` event and testing if width is more than height. There is also a sensor for this, but is is a bit problematic, take a look at http://www.jayway.com/2014/10/06/detecting-orientation-in-universal-apps-windows-phone-8-1/.

**.xaml**

```
<ContentDialog
    x:Class="App1.ContentDialog1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    SizeChanged="SizeChangedEvent">

    <--! Other Code -->

</ContentDialog>
```

**.cs**

```
private void SizeChangedEvent(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
}
```