# Why isn't the TextBox inside ContentDialog automatically scroll above keyboard

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1

I notice that if the `TextBox` is in a `Page`, then everything working perfectly. Whenever the `TextBox` is focused, it will scroll to the right position above the keyboard so that the user will be able to see the text as he is typing along. Thing is a little bit different for `ContentDialog` for whatever reason. `TextBox` is easily covered by the keyboard. Is there any obvious setting that I am missing?

I create a default `ContentDialog` and copied the code to a page. And get the following screenshots. Everything else is the same except that the upper level XAML elements is `<ContentDialog>` for the left column, `<Page>` for the right column.

Left Image - `ContentDialog` before keyboard pop up
Right Image - `Page` before keyboard pop up
[image] 
[image]

Left Image - `ContentDialog` after keyboard pop up
Right Image - `Page` after keyboard pop up
[image] 
[image]

Here is the related code:

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <TextBox Name="email" Header="Email address"/>
    <PasswordBox Name="password" Header="Password"/>
    <CheckBox Name="showPassword" Content="Show password"/>

    <!-- Content body -->
    <TextBlock Name="body" Style="{StaticResource MessageDialogContentStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap">
        <TextBlock.Text>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Why isn't the `TextBox` inside `ContentDialog` scrolled above the keyboard as it is like the in the `Page`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I've faced similar problem with the *TextBox* and have found [answer here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/99652e87-113c-47fa-a8e7-60f11fc9f160/virtual-keyboard-covering-textbox?forum=winappswithcsharp). Basically, once the keyboard is shown, the focused element is not moved up, you can correct this behaviour by making additional transform:

```cs
// add this code somewhere to your constructor of your page or content dialog - where the problematic TextBox is located
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Showing += (s, args) =>
{
    const double extraHeightBuffer = 20.0;

    UIElement focused = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement() as UIElement;
    if (null != focused)
    {
        GeneralTransform gt = focused.TransformToVisual(this);
        Point focusedPoint = gt.TransformPoint(new Point(0, focused.RenderSize.Height - 1));
        double bottomOfFocused = focusedPoint.Y + extraHeightBuffer;
        if (bottomOfFocused > args.OccludedRect.Top)
        {
            var trans = new TranslateTransform();
            trans.Y = -(bottomOfFocused - args.OccludedRect.Top);
            this.RenderTransform = trans;
        }
        args.EnsuredFocusedElementInView = true;
    }
};

Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForCurrentView().Hiding += (s, args) =>
{
    var trans = new TranslateTransform();
    trans.Y = 0;
    this.RenderTransform = trans;
    args.EnsuredFocusedElementInView = false;
};
```