# UWP Touch keyboard overlaps status bar

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Im devoloping a UWP app and I came across a problem.

In my input page when I tap a textbox the keyboard just "pushes" the UI upwards and this happens.

Normal screen:
[image]

Check at the top of  the page, you can see the problem:

[image]

Does anyone know a fix for this? Thanks!

Comment: In the past there was a problem that *TextBox* has been hid by the keyboard and [it needed some manual handling](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31220096/2681948). There is a chance that you can make something similar and maybe change the opacity of elements that are going out of the screen (or something similar).

Comment: @Romaz Thanks, i changed the the background of the status bar and it is "fixed" now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is default behaviour of the keyboard and can't be changed.

If the keyboard would not push the content upwards, it would overlap the actual `TextBox`, which you want to fill with text.

If your problem is the statusbar getting overlapped/underlapped with the page-content, you could try to change the color of the statusbar, it seems to be transparent at the moment.

See [this](https://stenobot.wordpress.com/2015/07/08/uwp-app-development-styling-the-mobile-status-bar/).

Comment: I followed your suggestion and it worked out pretty well!
Thanks! Going to send the app to the market now!

Comment: Glad to hear, you're welcome! It might be more of a workaround than a fix, but as long as it works...