# C# UWP Phone Rotate Navigation Bar Buttons

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, navigationbar, windows-10-mobile, screen-rotation

I am trying to accomplish the same effect of soft navigation bar buttons rotation that exists in the stock Camera App for Windows Phone 10.

How can one rotate phone soft navigation bar buttons in UWP application when user rotates the device using C#?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I could find is as follows:

Your best bet would be describing to Windows.Current.SizeChanged event and testing if width is more than height. There is also a sensor for this, but is is a bit problematic, take a look at [http://www.jayway.com/2014/10/06/detecting-orientation-in-universal-apps-windows-phone-8-](http://www.jayway.com/2014/10/06/detecting-orientation-in-universal-apps-windows-phone-8-1/)

[There was a good post about it on StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767273/how-to-get-the-device-orientation-changed-event-under-windows-phone) This also includes the answer in C# for you!

Comment: Be careful with using screen dimensions in universal apps. The fact that they are universal means the can run on a PC or other device, where the default view is landscape. Or if you are using page dimensions, remember that on a Windows 10 PC a universal app can run in a window of arbitrary size.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [SimpleOrientationSensor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.devices.sensors.simpleorientationsensor).

For example:

```
var sensor = SimpleOrientationSensor.GetDefault();
var orientation = sensor.GetCurrentOrientation();
```

You can also store the sensor in a field rather than a variable, and subscribe to its OrientationChanged event.